# StreamReader not finding end of file

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I simply need to read lines from a text file and show them. When I run this I can see that id does what I want, but after it reads the last value it just shows a blank form on my screen and does not move on. It seems like it can't find the end of the file or something. I don't get an error.

```
Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(Application.StartupPath & "\myfile.cfg")
    Dim Line As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim temp_array As Array
    Do While Line IsNot Nothing
         Line = sr.ReadLine
         temp_array = Line.Split("=")
        'MessageBox.Show(temp_array(0))
    Loop


End Using
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense, because `Line` is never assigned anything but an empty string. You never access `Line`  anywhere in the `Do While` loop to change it from that empty string to something else. Instead, you use something named `temp_array` that is never read  from in any way. Read the code you posted, and see if it makes any sense to you with that in mind. When you're using something as an exit condition,that something has to change within the loop so that condition is set.

Comment: I had edited the code for brevity, which left out a piece. I have fixed it. If you uncomment the messagebox, you would see each line in the file (if you create the text file.)

Comment: the temp_array was used  by the messagebox to show what was being read from the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is bad code because you're actually going to use `Line` before testing whether it's `Nothing`.  Here are two good options for looping through the lines of a text file:

```
Using reader As New StreamReader(filePath)
    Dim line As String

    Do Until reader.EndOfStream
        line = reader.ReadLine()

        '...
    Loop
End Using

For Each line In File.ReadLines(filePath)
    '...
Next
```

As you can see, the second is far more concise but it does require .NET 4.0 or later.

Comment: I didn't know about that second method - that rocks!

Comment: @technonaut31337, you can use `ReadAllLines` instead of `ReadLines` in .NET 2.0 or later. The difference is that `ReadAllLines` reads the whole file first and returns the lines as a `String` array. That's not great for big files of if you might not want to read everything. `ReadLines` is an iterator, so it exposes the lines one by one as you process them. Not useful if you need random access to the lines or you want to process them multiple times, but more efficient if you want to process them once only in order and especially if you might not need to read them all.